# TFS build service does not copy resource files into drop folder

Tags: tfsbuild

TFS 2010 build service copies the executable program and referenced assemblies into the drop folder as expected. However, it does not copy my resource files.

In detail, i have an *app.ico* file added to the project. The file's *Build Action* is set to *Content* and *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy Always*. The resource file does appear in the Debug folder where the project originally locates. Any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, it would be nice to enable extensive logging: Queue a new build having set Logging Verbosity = 'Diagnostic' (it's in the second tab named 'Parameters', 'Basic'.

Once the Build is finished right click on 'Builds' of Team Explorer and choose 'View builds'. Find the build that just ran and choose 'View Log'. Hit Ctrl+F and type 'Copy Files to Drop Location'. You should land on a spot that looks like this:

[http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/3226/so3x.png http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/3226/so3x.png](http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/3226/so3x.png)

This section should provide you with insight on what goes on in your build, I'd check that everything is as expected (especially that 'Source' covers the path where your missing resource files reside)

Comment: Problem solved. Your tip really helped. Thanks. 

By checking the log file closely, I noticed that I have been visiting and checking files in the source folder all the time and took them as the build output. Quite a stupid mistake. lol

Comment: this link be dead :(